# C++ Binary Tree Print Function Implementation

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, computer-science, breadth-first-search

I have to realize a binary tree in C++ and the problem is I have just started to code in C++. So I am really new to this topic and before I have coded in C or Python, not in C++.

I allready have created and initalized a binary tree, overgiving some leafes, a tree root element and now I want to see if what I've done is okay, hence it works or it's total nonsense.

Check my code, I use Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise:

```
"bintree.cpp"
#include "cseatreebin.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main() 
{
CSearchTreeBin MyTree;
std::cout << "#######################################################\n"
             "##################Binary Tree C++######################\n";

MyTree.Insert(5);
MyTree.Insert(15);
MyTree.Insert(7);
MyTree.Insert(-5);
MyTree.Insert(6);
MyTree.Insert(3);
MyTree.Insert(650);
MyTree.Insert(20);
MyTree.Insert(-20);
MyTree.Insert(510);
MyTree.Print();
MyTree.Print(); cout << endl;
//cout << "Amount of Treenodes: " << MyTree.GetNrOfNodes() << endl;
// Amount/Number should be calculated again if allready called once
//cout << "Amount of Treenodes: " << MyTree.GetNrOfNodes() << endl;
// ... only if the tree has changed... 
//MyTree.Insert(99);
//cout << "Number of treenodes: " << MyTree.GetNrOfNodes() << endl;
}
```

The custom headerfile:

```
"cseatreebin.h"
#ifndef SEARCHTREEBIN_H
#define SEARCHTREEBIN_H

class CSearchTreeBinInt;

class CSearchTreeBin 
{
public:
CSearchTreeBin(void);

void Insert(int);

void Print();

private:
CSearchTreeBinInt *pInternalRep;
};

#endif  // SEARCHTREEBIN_H
```

And my Binary Tree Initalationfile:

```
#include "cseatreebinint.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
CSearchTreeBinInt::CSearchTreeBinInt()
{
pRoot   = 0; //init and create treeroot
};

void CSearchTreeBinInt::Insert(int dat)  
{
Insert(pRoot, dat); //insert the root to the tree
}

void CSearchTreeBinInt::Insert(Node*& rpNode, int dat) 
{
if (rpNode == NULL) //check if there are nodes in the tree
{
rpNode        = new Node; //create new nodes if there are none
rpNode->dat   = dat; 
rpNode->pLeft = rpNode->pRight = NULL;
std::cout << "Binary Tree  has been initalized correctly-> inserting new Elements!\n\n";
 }
else
 {
   if (dat < rpNode->dat) {            // inserted data is less then existing?
       Insert(rpNode->pLeft, dat);    // put it on the left
       std::cout << "A Node has been inserted on the left!\n";
   }
   else {                              // if it's bigger then already existing nodes
       Insert(rpNode->pRight, dat);   // put it on the right side of the tree
       std::cout << "A Node has been inserted on the right side!\n";
   }
  }
  }
```

And in this file something is messed up, I don't know. I just want to print the elements, not always the text message "Call Printfunction!", I want to print them to output console. An graphical output could be done later, now I just want to make it run.

```
#include "cseatreebin.h"
#include "cseatreebinint.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;



CSearchTreeBin::CSearchTreeBin()
{
pInternalRep=new CSearchTreeBinInt; //init. and creation of Binarytree
};
void CSearchTreeBin::Insert(int dat)  //dat = is this the node which will   be inserted?
{
pInternalRep->Insert(dat);
}

void CSearchTreeBin::Print() {
int a;
std::cout << "Printfunction has been called!\n\n";
if (pInternalRep == NULL) return;

//CSearchTreeBin::Print(); // this won't work that easily
//pInternalRep->CSearchTreeBin::Print();
}
```

Somehow I/we have to find a way to print the containing elements, if they are already inside the tree, otherwise I have to find the error why the tree remains empty.

I just started to develop in C++, as mentioned above. And yes there some sample algorithms of BFS or something related but none of them has such a complexity like mine.

Comment: There is nothing complex about your tree—at least not visibly so. You  haven't actually shown us the `Node` class, but it appears to be a bog-standard `dat` integer and `pLeft` and `pRight` pointers, so any existing DFS, BFS, or other tree-traversal code should be trivial to adapt to your code, unless you just don't understand your own code at all. So pick a sample, try it, and show us where you get stuck, instead of just telling us that none of them will work for you.

Comment: Ok truth is I was a little bit to lazy for try and error.
But thanks for the hint!

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I skimmed through the text in your post and I can't even tell what is your problem. I know that you wrote some code and are unhappy about it, and not really much more.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Are you asking for potential improvements to your code? Is your code not working and you're trying to find the bug? Do you not know how to implement something?

Comment: Sorry I was very nervous at the moment I wrote this question. I want to improve my source code, more detailed the print function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code I can generate the missing header file. But some of my declarations may be different from yours. Your header file for the `node` and for the `CSearchTreeBinInt` looks like this, maybe:

```
/* "cseatreebinint.h"
 *
 */
#ifndef SEARCHTREEBININT_H
#define SEARCHTREEBININT_H

class Node
    {
public:
    Node *pLeft, *pRight;
    int dat;
    void Print(); //maybe this needs to be added
    };

class CSearchTreeBinInt
    {
public:
    Node* pRoot;
    CSearchTreeBinInt(void);
    void Insert(int);
    void Insert(Node*& , int );
    };

#endif  // SEARCHTREEBININT_H
```

There might be issues, because I (simply) put everything in the public scope.

You would need to implement the function `Node::Print`, because I added this function. E.g. a *simple*, recursive function to print your tree would look like this:

```
void Node::Print()
    {
    std::cout << "This node contains the value " << dat << std::endl;
    if (pLeft != NULL)
        {
        pLeft->Print();
        }
    if (pRight != NULL)
        {
        pRight->Print();
        }
    }
```

This is similar to something written in [Data Structures & Algorithms in Java, 2nd ed. by Robert Lafore](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672324539) pp. 381-382. If you wanted to keep programming in this part of computer science in C++, it would be my recommendation to study some general C++ and Data Structs and Algorithms in C++ (I hear Robert Sedgewick wrote a book).

For the final touch: In your function `CSearchTreeBin::Print` you would need to add an else-case and check for a valid root-node. If the root-node is valid, you call the recursive `Print` of the root-node and watch the magic happen.

You put in more questions in your code-comments and your code has some crude C++ parts (inconsistency between `0` and `NULL`, sometimes using `std::` and sometimes writing `using namespace`...).
This webpage might help you learn C++-elements in [English](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) or maybe [German](http://de.cppreference.com/w/). Also, welcome to C++-Programming.

**Edit:** You wouldn't name the function `Node::Print` like I did, but I'll leave it like this.

Comment: Great Work!
Sorry I have really forgot about the Headerfile :D
But yeah its nearly identical!